# knitr: delayed execution of chunks

Tags: r, knitr

I have an Rmd file where I have some functions and their descriptions, plus some functions' examples.
Since examples logically have to follow the functions they are related, their execution should be delayed with respect to their function source.

The `test.Rmd` file can be sketched as follows:

````
Function f
----------

The function f blah ....    

```{r f.code, eval=!delay}
f=function() g() # depends on g
```

f example
---------

Use f as follows:

```{r f.demo, eval=delay}
f()
```

Function g
----------

The function g blah ....

```{r g.code, eval=!delay}
g=function() return(1) 
```
````

Where the  `delay` label (for functions' examples) signals that the chunk should be executed after functions.

I use this function for knitting:

````
knit2=function(file){
  require(knitr); require(rmarkdown)
  delay=FALSE
  knit(file)
  delay=TRUE
  knit(file)
  render(file, "html_document")
}
```

knit2('test.Rmd')
````

Since I am no knitr expert, I wonder  if this is the proper approach to follow.

Comment: Why not just define `g` in the beginning in a chunk with `echo = F`? Then you can use `g` as much as you like and when you want to  display the definition just put the same code in a chunk with `echo = T` and `eval = F`.

Comment: @Gregor: with 2 funcs this makes sense. With 22 or 222 tracking the dependences is not feasible. Besides, as you see, the code follows documentation and doc order tends to be alphabetical or respecting document sections.